# translations of praise and worship in Chinese

Tags: translation

I've posted a question at Stackexchange, but I've deleted.

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/36809/20407
(It's visible for users whose reputation is larger than 10K? Maybe.)

and I think I've got the answer already.

**praise and worship**

The question is:

> Everybody had to **praise** Stalin, all the time.

Can I translate it into:

> 任何人都要在任何时候**歌颂**斯大林.

and

> whole Soviet people **worship** Stalin.

into

> 全苏联人都要**崇拜**斯大林.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everybody had to praise Stalin, all the time.
人们必须每天都称颂斯大林。

All Soviet people worship Stalin.
所有的苏维埃人民都崇拜斯大林。

如果有人不这么做，他们将立即送去古拉格！

Comment: Ah yes, Soviphobia is alive and well, unlike the Soviet Union itself :)